# 'orientationchange' JavaScript event callback won't execute play() method on Android, Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I am experiencing problems with the `play()` JavaScript method on Android, only on Google Chrome (it works well with Firefox).
This is the code:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
if (video) {
 window.onorientationchange = function() {
  // if I'm on Android-Chrome the alert correctly comes up, but the video won't start
  alert('x');
  video.play();
 }
}
```

It won't work using `addEventListener()`, either.
Nevertheless, this works on Chrome:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
if (video) {
 document.body.onclick = function() {
  video.play(); // video correctly starts
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not supported in Chrome, only Firefox.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/onorientationchange